# Can not access directory even i set permission to the group

Tags: windows-10, permissions, file-permissions, uac, effective-permissions

EDITED: The following fixed my problem but i i don't feel comfortable to disable the UAC. Why is that happen and how to fix that in a different want?

http://clintboessen.blogspot.com/2013/05/you-dont-currently-have-permission-to.html

I have directory C:\1. I disabled inheritance permissions. 
My LOCAL Administrators group has full access on that directory.

[image]

I logged in with my domain user which is part of the local administrators local group and i am getting the following error when trying to access that directory:

You don't currently have permission to access this folder.
Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder.

[image]

When i click "Continue", the OS grant Full Access to my domain user (that already part of the local administrators group) and i can enter to that folder.

[image]

I don't understand why the fact that i grant full access permission to the administrators local group is not enough while my domain user is part of it.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please do **not** edit your original question to include a potential answer.  Your update should either be a separate answer, or a comment appended to your original question.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the built-in Administrators group, create and use another, such as Files_administrators, with your user in it.
That new group will be not affected by UAC.
NB: Logoff/logon required.

Comment: What is so special in the adminiztrators group in terms of uac?

Comment: Even if you're in administrators group, when UAC on, your user use an simple user token in windows. You must be in an elevated mode to use administrator token. With UAC off, you're always in elevated mode, and soft you use too. Is for that you must keep UAC on. For other group you're in, you're always in in all mode.